# How do I connect a Juno LED light to a switch when the light receives power first?

Tags: led, recessed-lighting

I'm trying to connect a new LED light to a new single pole switch. I have a 14/2 main power feed coming in to the LED light first then a 14/3 wire going from LED light to switch. I feel like I have it wired correctly but the light does not turn on. Is it not possible to wire LED lights this way?

Comment: Yes, it is.  You made it easy by running 14/3 to the switch. Just mark the black or brown wire on the LED with red tape to redefine it as a red.  then you will have a situation where all the color codes just happen to match up.

Answer (score 1):

Harper's comment is, as usual, a correct summary of the solution. Here (copied from part of another question) is the full diagram:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkPfn.gif]

Light fixture junction box:

- All whites (neutral) together
- All grounds (green or bare) together
- Blacks from 2-wire & 3-wire cable together (hot)
- Mark light fixture black wire (may be labeled "hot" or "switched hot", but it should be the only wire or screw other than white/neutral and ground) with *red* tape.
- Reds from light fixture and 3-wire cable together (switched hot)

Switch junction box:

- All grounds (green or bare) together
- Black to "hot" screw on switch
- Red to "switched hot" screw on switch

If switch does NOT use neutral:

- Cap white (neutral) with a wire nut

Note that with a simple (not smart, not dimmable, not timer, etc.) switch there is no functional difference between the hot & switched-hot connections, but if there is a clear indication on the switch (or in the switch instructions), follow the directions.

If switch USES neutral (e.g., smart switch)

- White to neutral screw on switch.